# How i can use aggregation in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want aggregate result using Django ORM. Sample table structure is:

```
sample_table

| **id | user_id | viewed | likes |     abc**    |

|  1   | 123     |    1   |   1   |   0.1258965  |

|  2   | 222     |    0   |   1   |   0.0004585  |

|  3   | 123     |    0   |   0   |   0.0025802  |

|  4   | 123     |    1   |   1   |   0.2500245  |
```

I need results according to `user_id` e.g

```
[user_id, total viewd, total likes, total abc]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the values grouped per user, you will have to filter on the `User` model and `annotate` each row to include the aggregations.

Assuming that `sample_table` has the model `Sample` and a foreign key to `User` you can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.annotate(total_viewed=Sum('sample__viewed'), 
                      total_likes=Sum('sample__likes'),
                      total_abc=Sum('sample__abc'))
```

And each user row will also have the fields `total_viewed`, `total_likes` and `total_abc`.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. This worked for me with minor difference. Let me share it here.
Sample.objects.values('user').annotate(total_viewed=Sum('sample__viewed'), total_likes=Sum('sample__likes'),total_abc=Sum('sample__abc'))